# Target DOM nodes in the parent document from an iframe

Tags: javascript, http, iframe, https

I have an iframe running code under an https protocol, the document containing the iframe is http. It is not possible to change the protocol of either. The problem is that when JS events happen in the iframe, DOM nodes in the parent should be manipulated. Has anyone encountered a similar problem, and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If they're on the same domain, you should be able to access them via `window.parent`

Example, trigger a click

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('ele_id').click();
```

Make sure your iframe is included with a protocol-less url. For example:

```
<iframe src="//www.google.com" width="400" height="300" />
```

Comment: They are on http (parent) and https (iframe) domains.

Comment: That setup is insecure and is not ideal for the user. Setup the https on the parent domain and then you won't have to worry about the iframe being secure or not.